# How to find job that belongs to current user and display them in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to build a dashboard.html.erb page where only the jobs posted by the current user are shown.
This is my code so far:

```
<% @jobs.each do |job| %>
<% if job_author(job) %>

<h3 class="title is-4 index-title"><%= link_to job.title, job %></h3>

<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Any suggestions? Thanks
Update:

job model:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
    mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader

    def self.search(search)
        if search
            where(['title LIKE ? or description LIKE ?', "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%"])
        else
            all
        end
    end
end
```

user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  belongs_to :user
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  has_many :jobs
end
```

Comment: is `job_author` your current user ?

Comment: Is your `user` model has `has_many` relationship with your `job` model? If don't does `job` table has a foreign key of `user` table?

Comment: You must post the Job model and User model code for better answer.

Comment: @Bijendra Updated. I just added the job and user model.

Comment: @7urkm3n my current user is `current_user`

Comment: @catlover69 your User model has   belongs_to :user, it should be present in Job model for the association to work. has_many belongs_to association should work here.

Answer (score 0):

There will be multiple ways to answer this, below is simple solution. Update this as per your requirement.
Update your migrations in case of SQL Db for users and jobs table to have additional attributes.

```
class User
  has_many :jobs
end

class Job
  belongs_to :User
  #user_id should be present in db
end
```

Say your current logged in user is available in @user object. To get all the posted jobs by the user, use below code(validate the syntax)

```
@jobs = @user.jobs 

<% @jobs.each do |job| %>
  <h3 class="title is-4 index-title"><%= link_to job.title, job %></h3>
<% end %>
```

Comment: first of all, thank you for helping out, but unfortunately this code does not work

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! The problem was I(a complete idiot) forgot to def the dashboard in the controller. Anyway, thanks for your help! Have a nice day!

```
def dashboard
 @jobs = Job.all.order("created_at desc")
end
```